# Android onTouch must be triggered twice in order to trigger actionBar.show() and button position change

Tags: android, user-interface, actionbarsherlock, imagebutton, touch-event

I'm encountering a weird little problem with my `onTouchEvent`. When you touch the edge of the screen, it's supposed to show the action bar (using `ActionbarSherlock`, not the android actionbar), and move the button `"buttonClick"` down to accommodate the height of the action bar.

This works, but only if you touch twice. On the first touch, the action bar shows, and on the second touch, the button moves down. I have no idea why it doesn't do both during the first touch, and my searches around here have only turned up people having problems with it not firing at all, or a couple had problems where the onTouch was *only* firing twice, never just once.

My `onTouchEvent()` code is below, I'd really appreciate if somebody could help me understand why it's doing things this way.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.v(TAG, "New Touch");
            Log.v(TAG, "Screen Width: "+ screen_width);
            if (x >= (screen_width - 95)){
                int actionHeight = getSupportActionBar().getHeight();
                Log.v(TAG, ""+actionHeight);
                thumbParams.setMargins(0,actionHeight,0,0);
                thumbClick.setLayoutParams(thumbParams);
                params.setMargins(0,actionHeight,0,0);
                    buttonClick.setLayoutParams(params);
                getSupportActionBar().show();

            }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    }

return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of on touch event handler. Since you see the bar showing but not the button for the first time, check how you move the button. It's clear that your code is executing since the action bar shows up.

Comment: Hi neo, thanks for commenting! I'm moving the button by adjusting the margins for it in the code I pasted. I set the vertical margin to be the height of the actionBar, then I set the button's parameters to be the updated parameters. I'm puzzled, because it *does* run, it just has to be hit a second time before it does.
I tried placing it after the code which shows the actionbar, in case it is doing something weird where while it's hidden, the height is 0. Didn't make any difference in how it ran whatsoever.

Comment: Do you have the button visible before you touch?

Comment: Yes. The button starts out visible in the upper right corner of the app. When the onTouch() event is triggered, the actionbar is shown (in overlay mode, which is why I need to manually adjust the position of the button) and the button should be moved down by the height of the action bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific problem that was causing all of this was that the value for `getSupportActionBar().getHeight()` was `0` at the point I was trying to assign it to the margin. I tried a bunch of overly-elaborate ways to fix this, but it turned out in the end, all I had to do was move everything but `getSupportActionBar().show();` into the `ACTION_UP` case.

There can be a slight noticible lag if they leave their finger there too long, but most of the time it appears instantaneous, and it works on the first click now! I've put my adjusted code below in case my explanation is poorly worded.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            int x = (int)event.getX();
            int y = (int)event.getY();
            if (x >= (screen_width - 95)){
                getSupportActionBar().show();
            }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            actionHeight = getSupportActionBar().getHeight();
            Log.v(TAG, ""+actionHeight);

            thumbParams.setMargins(0, actionHeight, 0, 0);
            params.setMargins(0, actionHeight, 0, 0);
            thumbClick.setLayoutParams(thumbParams);
            buttonClick.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

return false;
}
```